# How to handle http_status_code in Kubernetes probe?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to implement Probe in Kubernetes

I understand that the probe returns success if `http_status_code >= 200 and <=399`

```
  containers:
    - name: myimage
      image: myimage:45
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: 5004
```

However, our application returns status code 404 (by design) in case of **success**.

How can I make the probe to succeed in this case?

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Change the probe to [execute a command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) instead of an http request. Kubernetes executes the command inside the container and determines the success based on the exit code of the command (0 for success, non-zero for failure)

1. Create a script `/health.sh` that uses curl to call your health check endpoint through `localhost`. Include a condition that sets the exit code to 0 (success) if the return code is 404, and 1 (failure) otherwise

```bash
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:5004) -eq "404" ]; then
  exit 0
else 
  exit 1
fi
```

2. Configure the probe with a command instead of a http request

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - /health.sh
```

If you don't want to modify the container, you can define the script inline in the command section like below

```yaml
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - if [ $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:5004) -eq "404" ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi
```